# Auto Generate Thumbnail

Tags: images, thumbnails

I wanna make soft corp of the thumbnail so that use the other plugins to that image corp. There is plugin I use , "Regenerate Thumbnail", after regenerating then there still old files exist. I gonna looking the backend `Media`, but the thumbnail is the `fileName-100x100.gif` and the srcset is `fileName-109x109.gif`.

After found out the files in the command line, I try to delete the 2 files directly. Despite removing the image, the image would auto-generate when I access the `Edit Image`.However, my setting didn't define any 100 by 100 or 109 dimension that hardly traces the problem.

So far as my solution, with the `Edit Image -> Scale Image` to suit my size then upload the new image after saving the new image with scaled size. Save and upload apparently not a good solution for me even it works, I have to found out the efficient solution that would handle the lot images process.

There is my `Setting-Media` :

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what your ultimate goal is? You have settings for a 100 width image (you can't height crop to 0), so if you upload a file that is 109x109 you will get a 100x100 cropped version.

Comment: HI Jacob, the dimension varies. The example I upload size is 490 × 111, I wanna got soft crop then would get 111x22.6.if the set height to 0 is not available , what number should I set? Thanks!!

Comment: Set the maximum height you want to allow and uncheck the hard crop checkbox.